# How can i set wish list for guest user also in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, adminhtml, wishlist

i need set Wishlist for guest users also

1. Guest can also able to add item in Wishlist.
2. after add item guest login into account that time Wishlist must be marge.
3. all Wishlist functionality must be working.

can any one guide me how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below extension is free.

https://store.belvg.com/guest-wish-list.html

Comment: thank you for sharing but this extention i all redy ty in that they creat custom new wishlist for guest user any thing else as simple.

Answer (score 0):

One more free option:

https://github.com/di-zed/m2-wishlist-guest

A module that will allow unauthorized users to use the wishlist on your website. The ability to share a wishlist via a URL has also been added.

Key Features:

- Working with a wishlist for guest customers.
- Sharing wishlist by URL.
- Automatic removal of old wishlists from the database.